# Spring MVC: @Value annotation with final variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a config.properties file:

```
date_format="yyyy-MM-dd"
```

My springmvc-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/T")
public class Test extends BaseController
{
    @Value("${date_format}")
    private static final String format; // Here, I want a final String as a constant

    @RequestMapping(value = "t2")
    @ResponseBody
    public String func(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = format) Date date)
    {
        return date.toString();
    }
}
```

I want to use @Value annotation on a final variable, which is used in the annotation @DateTimeFormat.

@DateTimeFormat requires a final String variable, this is why I need to use @Value on final variables. But it doesn't work currently. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your date format changing so often that you need to have it configurable in a properties file?

Comment: Why would you want to inject into a static field? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938529/why-cant-we-autowire-static-fields-in-spring for reasons not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question like this  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130425...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130425/spring-property-injection-in-a-final-attribute-value-java/47743165#47743165)

I'd remove the static modifier and do something similar to this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/T")
public class Test extends BaseController{

   @Value("${date_format}")
   private final String format; // Removed static

   public Test (@Value("${date_format}") format){
     this.format = format;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "t2")
   @ResponseBody
   public String func(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = format) Date date){
     return date.toString();
   }
}
```

This is known as [Constructor Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection).