# how to provide different transactional 'timeout' value based on different work environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

In my Spring 4 based project somehow I can not use `@Transactional` annotation and `<tx:annotation-driven>` ( as I want to make 'timeout' property's value configurable and want to read it's value from external property file so that non-technical guys can change timeout value based on environment, though timeout is constant value and it does not allow dynamic timeout value).

How can I develop it using Spring Transactional property (as java code) ? is it possible? like as below.

```
transactionObject.setTimeout(environment.getProperty("env.dev.timeout");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import value from properties file and use it in annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586968/how-to-import-value-from-properties-file-and-use-it-in-annotation)

Comment: @Arpit, should I take it as 'It is not possible'.?  improving my question as well.

Comment: yes it's not possible.