# Int from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In application.properties:

```
comment.length=3000
```

Now I'd like to use this constant:

```
@Entity(name="clients_client")
public class Client {
    @Column(length="${comment.length}")
    private String comment;
}
```

When compiling, I get this error:

> java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Comment: Ok, first, your Entity Client is not a Spring Bean, thus you cannot inject property values. Second, if you want to inject Spring Properties into a Spring Bean you should use `@Value`

Comment: similar to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586968/how-to-import-value-from-properties-file-and-use-it-in-annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very close to being a duplicate of [How to import value from properties file and use it in annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586968/how-to-import-value-from-properties-file-and-use-it-in-annotation), but I think there is a subtle difference between the questions.

You are trying to refer to a property in the `@Column` annotation by using `${comment.length}`. What is really happening is that you try to assign the `String` `"${comment.length}"` to the `length` attribute of the annotation. This is of course not allowed, it expects an `int`.

Java, or Spring, can not "magically" replace `${propertyName}` with a property. Spring, however, has [its own way of injecting property values](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation):

```
@Value("${value.from.file}")
private String valueFromFile;
```

Even if your entity was a Spring bean (for example annotated with `@Component`), and you injected the property with `@Value`, it cannot be used in the annotation. This is because values in annotations need to be constant, and is explained in more detail in the [accepted answer to the near duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33587079/1421925).

> Now I'd like to use this constant:

It simply is not a constant, it is determined at runtime.