# How to make final variable when @Value annotation is used

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have read similar post in the forum but actually could not find an answer. I am reading a property from an application.yaml file but I want to make that variable final. But compiler does not allow me to do it and says the variable might not be initialized. What I want to do is to use final as below. So this variable is defined in a controller class.

```
 @Value("${host.url}")
 private final String url;
```

So how can I do it final ?

Comment: You cannot. The only way to make this work is put the `@Value` annotation on an attribute int he constructor and then set the `url` in the constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130425/spring-property-injection-in-a-final-attribute-value-java

Answer (score 10):

The only way to achieve it is using constructor injection.

```java
@Component
public class MyBean {

    private final String url;

    public MyBean(@Value("${host.url}") String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```